# Nested Rules In Drools

Tags: nested, drools, rules, rule

I have a .drl file which contains more than 100 rules. There are approximately 40 rules like rule "1", some 35 like rule "2" and rest are like rule "3".

```
rule "1"
    when
        m: MyBeanClass( something1 == "train" && something2 == somevalue2)
    then
        m.setSomeThing(someOtherValue);
        update(m);
    end

rule "2"
    when
        m: MyBeanClass( something1 == "bus" && something2 == somevalue2)
    then
        m.setSomeThing(someOtherValue);
        update(m);
    end

rule "3"
    when
        m: MyBeanClass( something1 == "car" && something2 == somevalue2)
    then
        m.setSomeThing(someOtherValue);
        update(m);
    end
```

On firing all rules, all the rules will get executed, **which I do not want**. If "something1" is not equal to "train", then I want the **execution flow to directly go to the 41st rule** which is like the rule "2" here.

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Shardul

Answer (score 0):

I'd have three scoping rules for "car", "bus", and "train" to set a value, then 41 rule took in that scoped value and operated on it.

You still have to write 44 rules, but you don't have to repeat the 41 for each scoping case.

Comment: Thanks @duffymo!

So, you are suggesting that I should set another variable in the first 40 rules, so that if "something1" is NOT equal to "train", it will not execute the first 40.

Also, I am not sure what "scoping rules" means.

-Shardul